# jquery toggle open first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to achieve that the content is shown in an open state on startup. Currently it's loaded in a closed state. When the user opens it and closes it again it will reappear on reload so the user has to close it again to make his decision stored. https://jsfiddle.net/fwz35y4n/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clikon').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings().toggle();
      localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':visible'));
    });
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true') {
      $('#bar').first().show()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want the item to be displayed on page load? do you want to persist the last state of item when the page is refreshed?

Comment: yeah, right. the item should show up initially when the page loads and then store the last state (either if it was closed or kept open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check at startup if block is null

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clikon').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings().toggle();
      localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':visible'));
    });
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true' || block === null) {
      $('#bar').first().show()
    }
});
```

Comment: I just copied code from question and I didn't noticed :) Thanks! Edited